# I need particular ID for authentication for REST web service .?

Tags: android, uuid, android-webservice, android-authenticator

How to get any `device ID` that will `authenticate` and validate in `REST web service` for particular web service.

I can not use `IMEI` or `MAC` for storing in server and `authenticate` hex string .I found about `Secure Android ID`  but it has wide range ,if phone will `Reset/Factory wiped` and `Android ID` will reset.Also `credentials(Login/Pass/User Name etc.)` not usable for this.

I want to store one `Hex-string(64 or 128 bit)` which can be validate during only `SignIn/SignOut` scenario without `credentials` authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can send session id generated on server side in each API, when that user try to connect again you can validate that session id. You have to send session id in every API and you can validate that either server side or client side.